# Apply image transform after image is placed on page

Tags: image-transforms, image

I have an overview (i.e. list with around 150 items). Each of those items has an appropriate "teaser image". When a user is hovering a list item the appropriate teaser image fades in, on mouse out it fades out again.

As I didn't want to add all images into the page on load I am doing that effect with JS and loading the image url I've attached to each html list item as data-attribute, e.g.

```
//html
<a data-image="{{ asset.getUrl() }}">Item Title</a>

// js
link.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  image.setAttribute("src", imageUrl)
})
```

My problem is that I can't apply an image transform now as the image is not "generated" on page load but on hover only. Is there any way of applying an image transform in such a scenario?
*(I think I know the answer as the asset is coming from the server via JS and its url and not via rendering on load)*

Or would you simply recommend a using a plugin and applying the transform in the CP?

Comment: Couldn't you use https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#generatetransformsbeforepageload and set it to `true` to ensure they exist on page load?

Comment: Thanks @BradBell. Yeah but if they exist on load I would need to load all images on page load (and we're talking about 150 high-res images).

Comment: Maybe you could consider using the Imager X plugin: https://plugins.craftcms.com/imager-x, and / or the use of Imgix: https://www.imgix.com

Comment: @RomainPoirier Thanks for the input. That's what I went for then.